# Enclosing a router-link tag in an image in vuejs

Tags: image, routes, vue.js

Can I wrap or enclose a router-link tag in an image tag?

When I click the image, I want it to route me to the desired page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes you can, but it's the other way around: you need to wrap your image with the router-link tag

`<router-link to="/"><img src="path.jpg"/></router-link>`

http://jsfiddle.net/vns5vwj9/1/

Comment: Great stuff, @reinarg. Better that @retrograde's _update_, this one allows for more universal usage. I'm using it with an `svg` component (a `polygon`) inside an `svg` tag and still it works like a charm. So I don't need to generate independent `svg` files and load them on each `router-link`. It's directly embedded into the `svg` inline. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 16):

Slight update to @reinarg's answer.  You can also use the tag="img" option on the router link like this:

```
<router-link to="/" tag="img" src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg"></router-link>
```

router-link will render as an img

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/retrogradeMT/vns5vwj9/2/)

Comment: Keep in mind: the **tag** property will be removed in Vue Router 4: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link so the accepted answer should be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

Add a click event to your `img` tag:

`<img @click="methodName" src="image.jpg" alt="...">`

Now in your methods property add the methodName callback that you want to fire when you click the image like:

```
methods: {
  methodName() {
    return this.$router.push('desired-page-path');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another slight update to @reinarg's answer.
I had to explicitly set the height via css to make the image show up. (the height attribute on the img tag for some reason did not work when using RouterLink)

using

```
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-router": "^4.0.15"
```

-> template section

```
<RouterLink class="active" to="/home">
  <img src="@/assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" id="navbar-logo"/>
</RouterLink>
```

-> style section

```
#navbar-logo{
  height: 1em;
}
```