# How to use v-slot with img tag?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

How to add a link to an image properly using nuxt?

I am currently using `tag="img"` but it seems tag prop is deprecated. So is there a better way?

```html
<nuxt-link
      tag="img"
      :src="require('~/assets/ProfitApp-icon.png')"
      height="55"
      alt="logo"
      class="px-3"
      to="/"
    />
```

> WARN  [vue-router] 's tag prop is deprecated and has
> been removed in Vue Router 4. Use the v-slot API to remove this
> warning:
> https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link.

Comment: Why not using a slot? Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45962539/1295622

Comment: would you please write it in answer form so I can accept your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a slot like described here: [Enclosing a router-link tag in an image in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45962539/1295622)

```html
<nuxt-link to="/" class="px-3">
  <img
    :src="require('~/assets/ProfitApp-icon.png')"
    height="55"
    alt="logo"
  />
</nuxt-link>
```